# Querying ElasticSearch from Google Apps Script?

Tags: elasticsearch, post, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to populate a Google Sheet with data from ElasticSearch (ES). I haven’t found any resources that show how to go from ElasticSearch -> Google Sheets, but I thought I’d try it out. Using Apps Script, I am attempting to make a request to my ES index, but have been failing to do so. I am approaching the query as such:

```
// my .gs file - I call readFromTable() to run

var payload = {
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

var options = {
  "method": "post",
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password)
  },
};

function readFromTable() {
  Logger.log(options);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://" + ES_URL + ":9243/" + index_name + "/_search", options);
  Logger.log('Done.');
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Is there anything I am missing here? I continue getting a DNS error, but I am unsure where my mistake may be. Has anyone done this before?

I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Is the URL contained in `ES_URL` publicly accessible?

Comment: Ah, `ES_URL` is `[...].[organization].com`, and I just verified it wasn't publicly accessible by switching to non-org wifi and trying to access `ES_URL` - it didn't work :(. Do you know if there's a way to get around this? I am using G Suite via the same organization, but am unsure if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps Script executes on Google servers and the network requests initiated by `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` originate from Google servers. If the resource you want to access isn't publicly accessible, then you won't be able to reach it via `UrlFetchhApp`.

For reference, here's an excerpt from [the UrlFetchApp documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app):

> This service allows scripts to communicate with other applications or
>   access other resources on the web by fetching URLs. A script can use
>   the URL Fetch service to issue HTTP and HTTPS requests and receive
>   responses. The URL Fetch service uses Google's network infrastructure
>   for efficiency and scaling purposes.
>
> Requests made using this service originate from a set pool of IP
>   ranges. You can [look up the full list of IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip) if you need
>   to whitelist or approve these requests.

An alternative approach would be writing a program that runs within your environment (i.e. on a system that has access to your Elastic Search instance). This program could then use the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) to output results to a Google Sheet.

There are [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries) provided to facilitate writing such a program in a variety of languages. For instance, if you want to stick to Javascript, you can utilize [the Node.js client libraries](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I began to think the same way after running into this roadblock, until I saw that GCP API functionalities are currently blocked in the organization that I'm in.

I am curious about how viable your alternative approach would be in a use case where the most recent data is loaded into Google Sheets from ES upon load, and any edited data is sent to an API that updates ES and returns new values for that edited row. The first seems possible after looking through the Apps Script API, but I am hesitant to say the second is. I will push for the alt approach if so!

Comment: I can't really speak to the policy constraints in your environment. Apps Script cannot directly interact with non-publicly accessible systems, which is a hard technical limitation. Interacting with a private ES instance is a non-starter, for both read and write access. If you could use the Sheets API in an environment where you have access to the ES instance, then you can achieve the functionality you've described. However, if you're restricted from utilizing the Sheets API in the first place, it sounds like you have a policy issue to address.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll be sure to check whether certain APIs can be enabled, and whether using Sheets API is a viable option.